# TableViewCell in IB or Programmatically, which one is better for customization?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

I'm coding a custom TableViewCell and I need to set a background image for each one (actually same background image on all cells) and I'll add some labels for different type of texts (different in font, size, color, etc...) and a left image hosted on a web server. I've read a tutorial on how to make the TableViewCell using IB and add it to cellForRowAtIndePath method. It worked but the image size and texts in labels are not showing like I was seeing them in IB, not wysiwyg at all lol

So, I need your help to choose the proper way to customize these cells, should I go for the IB way or programming tips are better?

Thx in advance for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the size of your images is going beyond the expected size of the `imageView` property for the left image. That usually pushes around all the other UI elements. You can avoid that by setting `imageView.layer.masksToBounds` of your cell to `YES`.

In general, for the problem you describe, I would recommend doing everything programmatically. You will have the opportunity for abstraction and include your program logic more economically.

To keep your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method reasonably short, you can call your own `formatCellAtIndexPath` method and keep the formatting logic neatly separated from the content.

Answer (score 1):

I find it easiest to create the TableViewCell in IB to start with and then, when I have it looking the way I like it, to switch to a cell built programatically.